# Flutter Page Route Not Working With Two Materialapp Widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

it is showing this error

```
Could not find a generator for route in the _WidgetsAppState.
```

How can I navigate if my app has two `MaterialApp` widgets?

```
    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.brown,
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/HomeScreen': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(),


      },
    );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide more code showing how you triggering that route? Seems like you're using the first screen as a splash screen. If you navigate to `HomeScreen()` when some button is pressed then try using `MaterialPageRoute()` without using routes.

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provided some code but you can use [GlobalKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html).

Comment: how can i use it? sorry i am very new to flutter and i have never used keys

Comment: Can you provide some code please? I can help you better if I see some of your code.

Comment: Okay but this doesn't explain two *MaterialApp* widgets. There is only one MaterialApp widget.

Comment: 2nd materialapp widget is in 2nd screen which is not there (bcause there is too much code) so my problem is i have specified routes in this page but if i do same in that materialapp widget it show's me an error (Could not find a generator for route in the _WidgetsAppState.), so what i can do if i want to have rautes from that page also?

Comment: Why would you want, in first place, two MaterialApp widgets? You should probably stick with one and go through multiple screens and there you can apply your routes. Two MaterialApp should mean also what the name itself suggests, two individual apps that should be apart of each other.

Comment: thanks @miguelpruivo for your comment  i have solved the issue